# Background services are "allowed to continue running while in the background". Then why can't I get this to work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My application does meet the requirements for using `UIBackgroundModes` set to 'App plays audio'. My application plays music from the `MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer` class. What I'm trying to accomplish is to allow the user to set a timer for the music to stop. I'm having an issue with this. I've implemented the background task in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
        backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
    }

    if (backgroundSupported) {
        UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                }
            });
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                    if (rootController.sleepTimer != nil)
                    self.sustainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self  selector:@selector(checkTimeRemaining) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
                }

            });
        });
    }
}
```

with the `checkTimeRemaining` method:

```
-(void)checkTimeRemaining{
    NSTimeInterval totalSeconds = rootController.timerSetInSeconds.doubleValue;
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:rootController.startDateforSleepTimer];
    NSTimeInterval remainingTime = totalSeconds - elapsedTime;
    NSLog(@"remaining time %f",remainingTime);
    if (remainingTime <= 0) {
        [self.musicPlayer pause];
        [sustainTimer invalidate];
        self.sustainTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the timer doesn't go beyond the allowed 10 minutes. Since I'm playing audio (along with the Background mode set) I should be able stop the music at the specified time. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get it to work because the audio background modes setting allows audio processing to continue in the background until audio stops.  It does not grant any special permissions to the non-audio stuff, such as BackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, to continue.

But if you put time logging in an Audio Queue or RemoteIO Audio Unit buffer callback, it will keep getting called as long as audio continues to play.

Comment: Hi thanks. Would I still be using the `iPodMusicPlayer` controller in the case you describe? Where is the best place to start for leaning how to implement this? Do you suppose this is how some sleep timer apps are achieving this? They are still able to use the iPod music controller.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` only allows you execute a finite-length task your timer is still limited to the 10 minute time limit imposed by Apple. The Audio framework on the other hand internally allows the device to play audio in the background until the user stops it or the audio ends.

[Playing Background Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

> When the UIBackgroundModes key contains the audio value, the system’s
>   media frameworks automatically prevent the corresponding app from
>   being suspended when it moves to the background. As long as it is
>   playing audio or video content, the app continues to run in the
>   background. However, if the app stops playing the audio or video, the
>   system suspends it.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. There are a few apps in the AppStore that are implementing this somehow. They are using the iPodMusicPlayer controller to play the music, and once a user sets a time and locks the device, it will stop the music after x amount of minutes/hours. How are they achieving this?

Comment: The last line of my statement "or the audio ends" was your cue to explore how you could end the audio :). Look into what @hotpaw2 is recommending. If the audio queue keeps calling back to your code you should be able to stop it.

Comment: sorry, didn't quite catch on to that. Thanks for the help.